# Find the values of x that satisfy the equation $\Gamma (x-\sqrt{2x})=(\sqrt{x+1})!$

Tags: calculus

Find the values of x that satisfy the $\Gamma (x-\sqrt{2x})=(\sqrt{x+1})!$

Comment: If, as it appears, you had already asked Alpha and found 2.844 and 8 as solutions, it would be *much* better to state that and ask your real question.  Even better, include a link to the Alpha calculation.  It saves others reproducing the result.  If your real question is whether the 2.844 root is correct, or why Alpha finds it, or something like that, please say so.  You might well get more appropriate answers that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side demands that $\sqrt{x+1}$ be natural (or zero, if you don't think $0 \in \Bbb N$).  The left will quickly exceed the right as $x$ gets large, so it is easiest to check the $x$s that make $\sqrt {x+1}$ natural.  A little checking finds $x=8, (\sqrt {x+1})!=6=\Gamma(8-\sqrt{2\cdot 8})=\Gamma(4)$

Comment: 8 only or there are other values?

Comment: only x=8 or there are other values?

Comment: I didn't find any, and explained why I didn't have to look far.

Comment: now go to Wolfram alpha and find the roots of $\Gamma (x-\sqrt{2x})-(\sqrt{x+1})!=0$

Comment: I see the Alpha solution around $2.844$, but note that it translates the factorial into the Gamma function.  In my parlance, factorial is only defined for naturals, as I remarked in my answer, so the $2.844$ is not a correct solution. Alpha often does things like this, you need to check it.

Comment: Yes, I m with you because the factorial function deals with real number only

Comment: No, it deals with naturals only.  That is my point.

Comment: sorry the mistake from me ,I mean the positive integer numbers

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple I am obtaining two solutions :

$$ x = 2.844007074 $$

$$ x = 8 $$

The curve for the function $$\Gamma  \left( x-\sqrt {2}\sqrt {x} \right) - \left( \sqrt {x+1}
 \right) !
$$

in the interval $[2.1,9]$ is

[image]

Comment: Now which solution is right??

Comment: There are two solutions.

Comment: but this is impossible

Comment: what do say this right or not?

Comment: My opinion is that there are two solutions for the equation and the factorial is defined for all real values excepting  the negative integers.  Do you agree?

Comment: I think the solution x=8 only